# C# .net Selenium, how to insert a date and time using sendKeys()

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing a project where I need to grab the system date and insert it a txtbox.

I tried following but doesn't seem to work for me, I'm new to C# as well as Selenium, so I might be doing something silly.

```
query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("txtbox"));
DateTime y = DateTime.Today;
query.SendKeys("y");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did your code not work? Did it send "y" instead of the date?

```
var query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("txtbox"));
DateTime y = DateTime.Today;
query.SendKeys(y.ToString()); // you shouldn't send string "y", but the y.ToString()
```